# Responsive menu issue - not opening when clicked

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I have a menu that is responsive but the issue I have is that when it is re-sized the menu doesn't drop down when clicked. I have included a [codepen](http://codepen.io/gjweavr/pen/xVXmqP). Don't worry about the 3 lines not showing up, they do on the actual website.

Code for menu

```
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <nav class="cl-effect-4">
        <ul id = "nav" class="cl-effect-4">
            <li><a href="index.php?page=work">WORK</a><span class="slash-size">/</span></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=about">ABOUT</a>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript in order to handle the opening and closing of the menu. If you can use jquery, add something like this:

```
$('.show-menu').click(function() {
    $('#nav').toggle();
})
```

EDIT: ah now I see you want to make use of the checkbox css trick to show/hide your menu. Change `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #nav{` to `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav #nav{`

Comment: Thanks, that works but when I open the hamburger menu and close it then re-size back to normal it the menu disappears, any idea? It stays if I open the hamburger menu then re-size back to normal

Comment: It still has the same issue, when I re-size the browser to be smaller the hamburger menu shows up, I click it and the links show up. If I close it and re-size the browser back to full size the links disappear.

Comment: It doesn't have the issue with the css only approach. Don't forget to delete the javascript code I wrote earlier. It will work by just adding the nav bevore #nav as I said in my editted answer.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that part. Thanks a lot! I've updated the codepen and it works well. Any idea on how to fix the alignment? It's not fully covering the page properly.